# Hilbert-irreducible Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is  called Hilbert-irreducible if it satisfies the  following condition:

If a subspace $Y\subset X$ satisfies the  [parallelogram equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), then $Y$ is  necessarilly a  one  dimensional space.

Does $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ with operator  norm satisfy this  property? What  is  an example of  an infinite  dimensional Banach space with this property?

Comment: Note that $M_n \cong \ell_2^n \otimes_\varepsilon \ell_2^n$ isometrically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In other words, a (real) Banach space $X$ is Hilbert irreducible iff it has no $2$-dimensional subspace isometric to $\mathbb R^2$ with the Euclidean norm.

In $M_n(\mathbb R)$, the subspace $Y$ consisting of matrices whose entries below the first row are $0$  satisfies the parallelogram law.

The space $\mathbb c$ of real sequences converging to $0$ with supremum norm is Hilbert irreducible.  To prove this, consider two linearly independent members $x$ and $y$ of $c$.   It is easy to show that there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\|x + t y\|$ is 
an affine function of $t$ for $0 < t < \epsilon$. On the other hand, in $\mathbb R^2$ with Euclidean norm $\|(1,t)\|$ is  strictly
convex.

Comment: Is there a finite dimensional banach space which can not be  embedded in $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ isometrically?

Comment: The norm in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ is an algebraic function: $\|A\|^2 = \|A^T A\|$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T A$, and thus satisfies the characteristic polynomial of $A^T A$.  So take any finite-dimensional Banach space whose norm is a transcendental function of the coordinates in some basis.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What is  an explicit example of such transcendental norm?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$, for $|y| \le |x|$, $\|(x,y)\| = |x| \sqrt{1 + 4 \sin^2(x/(2y))}$; for $|x| \le |y|$, $|y| \sqrt{1 + 4 \sin^2(y/(2x))}$.