# The Finslerian version of the Nash embedding theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, finsler-geometry

Is it true to say that every  Finslerian manifold can be isometrically  embedded in some  $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$  with operator norm?

Note that every Riemannian  manifold can be embedded in some  matrix space isometrically, since the matrix space contains a  copy of the  standard $\mathbb{R}^{n}$:

[Hilbert-irreducible Banach space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253470/hilbert-irreducible-banach-space/253471#253471)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Burago and Ivanov](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=370&option_lang=eng) have shown that any compact Finsler manifold can be isometrically embedded into a finite-dimensional normed space. They also furnish examples of non-compact Finsler manifolds that can not be isometrically embedded in any finite-dimensional normed space.

Comment: @T.Amdehberhan  very interesting thanks

Comment: This paper is in Russian script. Can you provide the English version of the paper?